# Load webview with embedded URL containing .js and .css file

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, graph, uiwebview

I am doing project in which i want to show user data in graph..

i want to show graph using webview, html, javascript and css files.

in webview i am getting table instead of graph.

i am getting file path of all .js and .css file correctly.

i have already copied .js and .css file in copy Bundle Resources.

Here is my Code

```
NSURL* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"jquery.min" withExtension:@"js"];
NSLog(@"PATH %@",path);
NSURL* path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"03" withExtension:@"js"];
NSLog(@"PATH %@",path1);

NSURL* css1path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"common" withExtension:@"css"];

NSLog(@"CSSPATH %@",css1path);

NSURL* css2path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"03" withExtension:@"css"];
NSLog(@"CSS2PATH %@",css2path);




NSString *str  = @"<html lang=\"en\">";
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<head>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<meta charset=\"utf-8\">"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=800\">"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<title>Sleep Hour Graph of myBeats</title>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=%@\">",css1path];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=%@\">",css2path];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</head>"];

str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<body>"];

str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<div id=\"wrapper\">"];

str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<div class=\"chart\">"];

str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<h2>Weekly Sleep Graph/Hour</h2>"];

str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<table id=\"data-table\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"0\" summary=\"Sleep hours from 2013-08-12 to 2013-08-18\">"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<caption>Sleep in Hours</caption>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<thead>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<tr>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<td>&nbsp;</td>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<th scope=\"col\">%@</th>",Str1];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<th scope=\"col\">%@</th>",Str2];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<th scope=\"col\">%@</th>",Str3];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<th scope=\"col\">%@</th>",Str4];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<th scope=\"col\">%@</th>",Str5];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<th scope=\"col\">%@</th>",Str6];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<th scope=\"col\">%@</th>",Str7];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</tr>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</thead>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<tbody>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<tr>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"<th scope=\"row\">Sleep in Hours Per Day</th>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td>%@</td>",Str11];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td>%@</td>",Str22];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td>%@</td>",Str33];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td>%@</td>",Str44];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td>%@</td>",Str55];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td>%@</td>",str66];
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<td>%@</td>",Str77];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</tr>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</tbody>"];
str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</table>"];

str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</div>"];

str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</div>"];

str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=%@\"></script>",path];

str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=%@\"></script>",path1];

str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</body>"];

str=[str stringByAppendingString:@"</html>"];
NSLog(@"HTMLFINAL %@",str);
[webview loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];

[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:str];
```

output i am getting:

[image]

desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `href` and `src` attributes are missing a leading `\"`.

```
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=%@\">",css1path];
                                                                 ^
```

Comment: i am getting this.. whole path comes here : <script type="text/javascript" src=file://localhost/Users/letsnurture/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/0A91568B-0FCD-4573-8DD0-3648FA678422/MyBeats.app/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah, that's why—it's invalid, needs a quote before the `file:`.